# jQuery DataTables: check all checkboxes on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-checkboxes

I have a grid which is based on `jQuery DataTables Checkboxes`. It pretty much looks like the basic example that `gyrocode` have on their [webpage](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/)
Does anyone know if I can have all checkboxes checked when the table first loads please (including the master checkbox, the one at the top that checks/unchecks all with a single click)

I tried `$("input.dt-checkboxes").prop("checked", true);` but that checks only the entries that are currently shown on the datatable's page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `cells.checkboxes.select()`, filter the cells but, but we actually return true for all rows here, a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/m8us7z4c/1/):

```
...
'initComplete': function(settings){
  var api = this.api();

  api.cells(
    api.rows(function(idx, data, node){
      return  true;
    }).indexes(),
    0
  ).checkboxes.select();
},
...
```

Comment: Yes, correct. I actually got something similar. I used `createdCell': function(td){this.api().cell(td).checkboxes.select()}` with `deferRender': true`. I am not sure if there is a different but your answer is happily accepted. Many thanks for looking into this